# The ethnet adapter can't get IPv4 adresse from Fritz Box

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb, ethernet, netplan

I've got a Dell XPS 15 9500 (Ubuntu 20.04). I'd like to use an ethernet adapter. I've bought a DA310 but I can't get the ethernet connection to work.

When I connect the USB-C cable, these devices show up in the `lsusb` list:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
```

Update: results from `dmesg | grep -i r815`:

```
[    5.774392] r8152: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    5.774488] r8152: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    5.875871] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Using pass-thru MAC addr 74:78:27:b4:aa:c4
[    5.924872] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 eth0: v2.14.0 (2020/09/24)
[    5.924873] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
[    5.924894] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    5.947443] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 enx747827b4aac4: renamed from eth0
[ 9383.034066] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 enx747827b4aac4: carrier on
[11261.203519] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 enx747827b4aac4: carrier off
[11264.531381] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 enx747827b4aac4: carrier on
[11374.610728] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 enx747827b4aac4: carrier off
[11377.235344] r8152 4-2.1:1.0 enx747827b4aac4: carrier on
```

enx747827b4aac4 has no IPv4 adress from router.
Network-Information via `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 14.3
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
       Logischer Name: wlp0s20f3
       Version: 00
       Seriennummer: dc:41:a9:fb:bc:47
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.10.0-1029-oem firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.178.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:604b11c000-604b11ffff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Physische ID: 3
       Bus-Informationen: usb@4:2.1
       Logischer Name: enx747827b4aac4
       Seriennummer: 74:78:27:b4:aa:c4
       Größe: 1Gbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v2.14.0 (2020/09/24) duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

`cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Why did wlp0s20f3 get IPv4 address and enx747827b4aac4 not?

Comment: It's working now. helpful: https://www.ubuntu-server.com/ubuntu/how-to-configure-the-ubuntu-dhcp-client/#Configure_DHCP_through_netplan

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me now. I installed netplan and started with netplan.

Helpful Page: https://www.ubuntu-server.com/ubuntu/how-to-configure-the-ubuntu-dhcp-client/#Configure_DHCP_through_netplan